# call telephony manager in a list fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use this code:
TelephonyManager    telephonyManager;

```
        telephonyManager  =  ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService( Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );
        imeistring = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

to call the id of the phone, but when I'm inside a List Fragment, it gives me errors.. "cannot make a static reference in a non-static method  getSystemService(String) from type Activity.

How else would I be able to get this phone id?

It works in Activity files, but not ListFragments...

Answer (score 2):

```
 telephonyManager  =  ( TelephonyManager )getActivity.getSystemService( Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );
 imeistring = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: I tried this, but it asks me to create a getActivity parameter. When i do, it's null..

Comment: nevermind. it's because i need telephonyManager  =  ( TelephonyManager )getActivity().getSystemService( Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE );